# Refreshing webpage from script

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, reload

I have to refresh a webpage using VBScript after a specific time interval. If the tab is closed by the user it should reopen it.

I have this code:

```
While Err.Number==0
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pziVbI7XaDs"
    refreshSeconds = 60
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .menubar   = True
        .toolbar   = True
        .statusBar = True
        .visible   = True
        .Navigate url
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    Do While Err.Number = 0
        Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Loop
        Wscript.Sleep refreshSeconds * 1000
        ie.Document.Location.Reload True
    Loop
Wend
```

But the code only refreshes the webpage and does not reopen the closed tab.

Can someone also tell me what is the `Err.Number = 0` means?

Comment: I execute your script on windows 7 and IE11 and it is just open new tab whenever I execute it again.No matter if the old tab is open or close.Also I didn't receive any error message.

Comment: And you have to delete the last char from your script area `

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your `err.number==0`, this is VB syntax and there is no `==` only `=` as is equal.

But you can still just reopen it and do not refresh the page.